# Force validation on disabled entries

Tags: entries, entrymodel

Craft CMS allows you to save entries without any validation if it's not an enabled entry.

Is it possible to disable this? I've had a dig through the core Craft code but can't actually find the conditional that makes this happen. It doesn't seem to be in the Entries service or model or their parents.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the [Always Validate](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/always-validate) plugin does what you're looking for.

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar. Thanks Brad! :)